# How to drop check constraint in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

All I need to know is how to drop check and primary key constraint on my table.

Here is my table schema.

```
create table time_slot
  (time_slot_id    varchar(4),
   day      varchar(1),
   start_hr    numeric(2) check  (start_hr >= 0 and start_hr < 24),
   start_min    numeric(2) check (start_min >= 0 and start_min < 60),
   end_hr      numeric(2) check (end_hr >= 0 and end_hr < 24),
   end_min    numeric(2) check (end_min >= 0 and end_min < 60),
   primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_min)
  );
```

Comment: MySQL ignores `check` constraints, so there's no need to drop them.

Comment: You can drop the primary key with `DROP INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE`. Read the documentation for the full syntax.

Comment: what about SQL(PL/SQL) ? I'm trying to update my table but it says constraint error.

Comment: Use `ALTER TABLE` for both.

Comment: alter table not working for my code. Try to insert these values in this table
`insert into time_slot values('M','S',30,0,15,35);`

Comment: Show the `ALTER TABLE` command that you tried.

Comment: `alter table time_slot drop constraint SYS_C0010437;` I've taken constraint name from dba tables.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL.

Comment: so, no one knows or wants to help?

Comment: What happened when you ran that command (which looks like Oracle); what error did you get?

Comment: **ORA-02290:check constraint(SYS.SYS._C0010701) violated**

Comment: Huh? Is that when you try to drop the constraint, or when you run the insert you mentioned earlier? It isn't clear what you're really asking.

Comment: Does this sound like one of those situations where the OP has a problem, and tries to solve it by smashing everything around? If people created those constraints on your tables, perhaps they had a reason; don't try to "make it work" by breaking everything else! Maybe you have a good reason to want to do this, but if my hunch is right, I would fire you if you were my employee and you were solving problems this way.

Answer (score 3):

The commands you've shown are fine for Oracle:

```
create table time_slot
  (time_slot_id    varchar(4),
   day      varchar(1),
   start_hr    numeric(2) check  (start_hr >= 0 and start_hr < 24),
   start_min    numeric(2) check (start_min >= 0 and start_min < 60),
   end_hr      numeric(2) check (end_hr >= 0 and end_hr < 24),
   end_min    numeric(2) check (end_min >= 0 and end_min < 60),
   primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_min)
  );

Table TIME_SLOT created.

select constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
from user_constraints where table_name = 'TIME_SLOT';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C SEARCH_CONDITION                                                                
------------------------------ - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_C00117031                  C start_hr >= 0 and start_hr < 24                                                 
SYS_C00117032                  C start_min >= 0 and start_min < 60                                               
SYS_C00117033                  C end_hr >= 0 and end_hr < 24                                                     
SYS_C00117034                  C end_min >= 0 and end_min < 60                                                   
SYS_C00117035                  P                                                                                 

alter table time_slot drop constraint SYS_C00117031;

Table TIME_SLOT altered.

alter table time_slot drop primary key;

Table TIME_SLOT altered.
```

So either you're using an old constraint name (and have since dropped and recreated the table); or there are different instances of the table (in different schemas) and you're seeing the wrong one in `dba_constraints`; or you're trying to modify a table in another schema without prefixing it. Or, possibly, something I haven't thought of, which would be revealed by sharing the error you get... (such as not having permission to drop the constraints, as @mathguy pointed out - which might be a good thing)

---

In a later comment you said you're getting a constraint violation, which seems to be related to the insert you mentioned earlier, not the attempt to drop the constraint:

```
ORA-02290:check constraint(SYS.SYS._C0010701) violated
```

Firstly, unless you've edited it to hide your real schema name (which you may have - there's at least an extra period) that suggests you're creating and modifying things in the SYS schema. If you are doing that stop, create a new user/schema for your self, and only work in that. You should not be messing around in the built-in schemas.

Secondly, if that is from the insert, it's because you're trying to set `start_hr` to 30, which is exactly what the constraint is there to prevent. You aren't helping yourself by not supplying the column list; if you do so it's a bit more obvious:

```
insert into time_slot (time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_min, end_hr, end_min)
values ('M', 'S', 30, 0, 15, 35);
```

so you're trying to have start time 30:00 and end time 15:35, which just doesn't make sense.

Dropping the constraint is not the answer here, you need to provide valid data. But if you did want to, the relevant constraint name is provided in the error message - you can see which one it is from dba/user_constraints, and if you wanted to drop it you'd do:

```
alter table time_slot drop constraint SYS_C0010701;
```

But I really think that's the wrong approach to your real problem.

---

You might also want to consider using an interval or a date (with a fixed, dummy date part) rather than separate hour and date columns; the validation would then be automatic.

Comment: Actually, if the OP is trying to fit a square peg in a round hole, one would hope he doesn't have the privileges needed to DROP CONSTRAINT. And if he does, and he succeeds in dropping them, perhaps that will remind the other folks in his group why they need to take granting privileges seriously. (The OP did not explain why he didn't succeed when he tried - perhaps it was "missing or invalid privilege"?)

Comment: This just reminded me of a couple of other questions I saw either here or on OTN recently (I don't remember which) - folks who wanted to know if there is any way to see when a constraint was created... I couldn't think of a good reason for such a request, but I can see a supervisor trying to see if anyone is messing with the constraints! That may have nothing to do with this OP, but it just crossed my mind...

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER TABLE time_slot DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE time_slot DROP CHECK CHECK_NAME;
```

Comment: the first commant is for drop primary key from your table and second for to drop check contraint that you want to drop,so simple add your field name in place of CHECK_NAME that check you want to drop

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow `drop check` ([at least in 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2104014)).

Comment: i didn't understand what u want to say

Comment: In this case I see there was confusion about the actual DB used. However, on SO we see this very often - even when a poster very clearly and accurately tags a question as "Oracle", say, people will give DB2 or SQL Server answers because that's what they know, even though the answer has no analog in Oracle.

Comment: but what the confusion in this we definitly have to create DB first then create table.My answer is only for dropping the constraint not for creating DB but if you require then i provide to u